# Proof for a differential equation

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is as follows: Show that the general solution to the differential equation 
\begin{equation}
x \frac{dy}{dx} = y\ln(x) 
\end{equation}
is  $y = Cx^{\ln\sqrt{x}}$
[image: This is what I tried in class, however did not get to the correct solution/proof]

I thought there was a typo, but it is not, since if we differentiate the second part we can get to the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Separation of variables:
$$
\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{\log x}{x}dx,
$$
$$
\log |y| = \frac{1}{2}\log^2 x+C.
$$
Therefore
$$
y=Ke^{\frac{1}{2}\log^2 x}.
$$
Now,
$$
x^{\log \sqrt{x}}=e^{\log\sqrt{x}\log x}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\log^2x}.
$$

Comment: I should point out that your method does not work if $y=0$ in an interval. However, your final answer includes that answer. In other words, a rigorous answer would need more work, but most calculus classes do not require that much rigor.

Comment: Yes, of course. However I believe that the OP could not catch a simple "algebraic" manipulation.